# inserting data into SQL DB from C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert values into my SQL database, the query works on the SQL side but when it comes to implement it from C# ASP.NET, it will not insert anything into the SQL database. The code is as follows:

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sanctuary(SName) values('test')", con);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into species(Name) values('test1')", con);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into breed(SpeciesID, BreedName, FoodCost, HousingCost)  SELECT SpeciesID, ('breed'), ('12'), ('21') FROM species", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I'll expect at least the last command to run. Did you get any error message?

Comment: Why did you tag this as MySQL? You are using the SqlConnection and SqlCommand classes, which are for MS SQL and have nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: You only execute the last command, so there is nothing in `species`. Since there is nothing in `species`, the select returns no results so nothing gets inserted into `breed`.

Comment: @Steve, actually the first command was running and no the rest. But thanks so much for your answer below, helped a lot!!! I've spent four days researching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only execute the last command, so there is nothing in `species`. Since there is nothing in `species`, the `select` returns no results so nothing gets inserted into `breed`.

Also, keeping an `SqlConnection` object on the page level is not a good idea. SQL connections should be opened right before executing queries and disposed immediately after.

A better code would look like this:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(var com = new SqlCommand("insert into sanctuary(SName) values('test');insert into species(Name) values('test1');insert into breed(SpeciesID, BreedName, FoodCost, HousingCost)  SELECT SpeciesID, ('breed'), ('12'), ('21') FROM species", con)
    {
         con.Open();
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You can, of course, execute each SQL statement separately (though in this case it's not the best course of action since it means 3 round trips to the database instead of just one):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(var com = new SqlCommand("insert into sanctuary(SName) values('test');", con)
    {
         con.Open();
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         com.CommandText = "insert into species(Name) values('test1');";
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         com.CommandText = "insert into breed(SpeciesID, BreedName, FoodCost, HousingCost)  SELECT SpeciesID, ('breed'), ('12'), ('21') FROM species;";
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: separate commands IS the best, if an error occurs it can be traced.  Combining the statements into 1 SQL command is a bad practice.

Comment: @Rob That's usually correct, but I'm not sure it's correct here.

Comment: yes it is bad practice, it's like saying GOTO is bad, but if it's only 1 once in a while then that's OK - Wrong: no, Bad: yes.  The temptation to grow/add-on multi-command statements is there, the temptation to do it in future projects is there, the temptation to make that a habit is there, and then what of the next guy that comes along to debug your code.  As to the "round trip time" - negligible compared to the actual database execution time.

Comment: @Rob You do realize that a lot of database activity involves more than a single statement, right? Are you also against using stored procedures? If not, are you against using multi-statements stored procedures?

Comment: you realise if you combine statements together into 1 sqlcommand you only get 1 result back, or is effective recovery/debugging unnecessary?   True, I'm no fan of SP (not that I never use them),, I write systems that interact with multiple vendor/types of databases simultaneously - each has their own peculiarity as to how SP are written and happen/flow which I why I actually do try hard to avoid SP).  But my point: You don't get to work on live/mission critical systems when you start your hobby/career inculcating bad practices - sooner you learn to do it properly the better.  Just dont do it.

Comment: @Rob that I can relate to. I even agreed with your first statement. This is why I've shown both options in my answer. However, I do believe that it's good to know the options - and concatenating simple, almost "full proof" statements into a single command object doesn't strike me as something to fear in debug. I agree that it's better to start off with best practices but it's also good to know there are other alternatives (that might be useful some times)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute three commands together you merge the sql of the three commands in a single string separating them with a semicolon (See [Batch of Sql Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/batches-of-sql-statements))

```
   string cmdText = @"insert into sanctuary(SName) values('test');
                      insert into species(Name) values('test1');
                      insert into breed(SpeciesID, BreedName, FoodCost, HousingCost)  
                      SELECT SpeciesID, ('breed'), ('12'), ('21') FROM species";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The first problem in your code is that you need to execute each single command and not just the last one. Finally, if you don't see even the insert for the last command could be because your table *species* is empty and thus the final command has nothing to insert.

Last note, the point underlined by Zohar Peled about NOT keeping a global connection object around, is very important, follow the advice.

Comment: What if I wanted to call a textbox for its value a, how can I do this, please? something along the lines of: @"insert into sanctuary(SName) values('"+country+"')";
                      "insert into species(Name) values('"+specie+ "')";

Comment: Now this is different. instead of a constant string you need to insert a user input value. This could be done writing a parameterized query. I suggest you to search for this words _c# parameterized query_ and then try to create one by yourself. If you have problems post a new question (this way more people will look at your problem than in a closed and accepted question)